# How to connect the rings to the coil

Tags: mechanical-engineering, generator

Hello I was recently watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ylgb8FFMgd4) video and I have 1 question the video doesn't explains.It says that when the coil will start rotating the rings will start rotating as well.

[image]

But how do I connect the coil to them rings?Do I glue the coil on them??

Answer (score 0):

The wires are usually soldered to the rings, there may also be a clamp type joint as well.

On dynamos, where there were some 40  wire ends coming to the commutator, each had to be soldered to the correct segment - a job I remember fondly...

What you then do with those rings is to split them so each ring is in two halves and then you cam make a commutator...

Comment: for dc generator yes but an ac generator is much simpler to be built so I will start from there. Since the wires are soldered to the ring if I rotate the ring the coil will start rotating correct?